# How to display Up button on another Activity using Navigation Architecture Component

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

Say that I am on parent `ActivityA` which has a Fab button. On clicking the Fab button, it opens `ActivityB`.

`ActivityB` contains the navigation graph. So there I have setup the navigation component like:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph())
        .build();
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
```

Now the problem is that, I can not display the up button to go to parent activity. On `AndroidManifext.xml`, the code is:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.ActivityB"
    android:label="Activity B"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:parentActivityName=".ui.ActivityA">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.ui.ActivityA" />
</activity>
```

So, my question is how to display the up button?

---

@ianhanniballake, the above one is working with your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54799638/2519748) but not this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder()
        .build();
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration);
```

Or:

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [Update UI components with NavigationUI documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-ui#appbarconfiguration):

> By default, the Navigation button is hidden when a user is at a top-level destination of a navigation graph and appears as an Up button in any other destination.

Therefore you can get the Up button to display on **all** destinations by passing in an empty set of top-level destinations. When you cannot move Up in the navigation graph, the `OnNavigationUpListener` you've set via [`setFallbackOnNavigateUpListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/AppBarConfiguration.Builder.html#setFallbackOnNavigateUpListener(androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration.OnNavigateUpListener)) will be called, allowing you to trigger your activity's navigate up functionality:

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder()
    .setFallbackOnNavigateUpListener(new AppBarConfiguration.OnNavigateUpListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigateUp() {
            // Trigger the Activity's navigate up functionality
            return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
        }
    }).build();
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

 // Make sure to call NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration);
 // in your Activity's `onSupportNavigateUp()`
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but what if I want to have multiple top level destinations?

Comment: If you want to hide the Up button on multiple destinations, pass them all into the `AppBarConfiguration.Builder` [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/AppBarConfiguration.Builder.html#AppBarConfiguration.Builder(int...)).

Comment: And one last question, what if I want to set it up without `setSupportActionBar` and with `setupWithNavController`? In `ActivityB.xml`, I will add `app:navigationIcon="?homeAsUpIndicator"` to Toolbar. If I was't clear, should I update the question?

Comment: Calling `setupWithNavController` on your Toolbar would be enough - as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.html#setupWithNavController(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar,%20androidx.navigation.NavController,%20androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration)), it automatically handles setting the icon and calling `navigateUp` for you. Note: you don't need to call `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` when using the ActionBar either, NavigationUI does that for you.

Comment: It's not working actually. I'm updating the question.

Comment: You still need to include the `OnNavigateUpListener` callback when using a Toolbar. You'd just call `onSupportNavigateUp()`, not `super.onSupportNavigateUp()` if you're not overriding that callback on your Activity.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks again.

Comment: in addition to @ianhanniballake answer if you also want to enable up button for all the fragments just in one place , not in each fragment's `onViewCreated()` as says the documentation , check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67789570/10390808

Answer (score 0):

The following method will be solved your problem

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val navController: NavController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder().build()
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration)

        fab.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_nav_setting_to_nav_notification)
        }
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(
            navController,
            appBarConfiguration
        ) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```