# android navigation component up button, arrow displays but popTo not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using the jetpack navigation component with a very simple set up, one activity (MainActivity) and 4 fragments

MainFragment,

CardPreviewFragment,

createCardFragment,

and AddPredictionChipsFragment,

The NavigationUI component sets up my nav controller with my toolbar, I have actions set to each destination and popTo also set for each. I can successfully navigate to each of these fragments and the toolbars title changes correctly and home icon displays a back arrow correctly but pressing the arrow to use the popTo action does nothing (SIDENOTE if i set a pop enter and exit animation and use the back button to go back the animation is used). Any ideas welcome, below is the relevant code edited for brevity

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
  setNavigation();
 }

private void setNavigation() {
 navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_fragment);
 NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController);
}

@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 Intent i;
 switch (item.getItemId()){
  case R.id.preferences :
    //code
    return true;
  case R.id.share :
    //code
  case R.id.create :
    //code
  case R.id.about :
    //code
    return true;
 }
 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

My main activity does use the action bar, showing a search bar and some menu items, I don't know if this is somehow affecting it (have tried to remove them to no change)

content main holds a nav host fragment

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
  app:defaultNavHost="true"
  app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_main"/>
```

Fragments use androidx : EditFragment extends Fragment and do not use menu options or anything similar they are all just standard fragments, here is my navigation graph

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <navigation 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/nav_main"
      app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">
      <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.sealstudios.simpleaac.ui.MainFragment"
        android:label="Simple AAC"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">
        <action
          android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_cardPreviewFragment"
          app:destination="@id/cardPreviewFragment"
          app:popUpTo="@+id/mainFragment"
          app:popUpToInclusive="false"/>
        <action
          android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_createCardFragment"
          app:destination="@id/createCardFragment"
          app:popUpTo="@+id/mainFragment"
          app:popUpToInclusive="false"/>
      </fragment>
      <fragment
        android:id="@+id/cardPreviewFragment"
        android:name="com.sealstudios.simpleaac.ui.CardPreviewFragment"
        android:label="Preview Card"
        tools:layout="@layout/preview_card_fragment">
        <action
          android:id="@+id/action_cardPreviewFragment_to_createCardFragment"
          app:destination="@id/createCardFragment"
          app:popUpTo="@+id/mainFragment"
          app:popUpToInclusive="false"/>
      </fragment>
      <fragment
        android:id="@+id/addPredictionChipsFragment"
        android:name="com.sealstudios.simpleaac.ui.AddPredictionChipsFragment"
        android:label="Add Predictions"
        tools:layout="@layout/add_prediction_chips_fragment_layout"/>
      <fragment
        android:id="@+id/createCardFragment"
        android:name="com.sealstudios.simpleaac.ui.CreateCardFragment"
        android:label="Create / Edit"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_create_card">
        <action
          android:id="@+id/action_createCardFragment_to_addPredictionChipsFragment"
          app:destination="@id/addPredictionChipsFragment"
          app:popUpTo="@+id/createCardFragment"
          app:popUpToInclusive="false"/>
      </fragment>
    </navigation>
```

and here is an example of me calling one of the actions,

```
  Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(),R.id.main_fragment)
  .navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_cardPreviewFragment);
```

this action navigates to the correct place getting the correct title from the label but does not allow me to navigate back/up using the arrow, full project is [here](https://github.com/martipello/SimpleAAC)

**UPDATE** This is reproducible

I can create a new project add the navigation component and 2 fragments add the nav graph and add the navhost to content main, and i end up with the same behaviour (arrow appears but wont popTo anything including the graph itself) I'm using "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0-alpha03" and "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0-alpha03" and I've made a sample project [here](https://github.com/martipello/navigation_component_pop_issue/tree/master) and raised a bug in the issue tracker

**UPDATE** google have come back to me and said this is the expected behaviour although I'm fairly sure he's misunderstood and definitely hasn't run the example I sent over

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When using `setupActionBarWithNavController()`, you need to override `onSupportNavigateUp()` to trigger the Up icon in the Action Bar as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#action_bar):

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_fragment).navigateUp()
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

Comment: yup found out last night after the google dev highlighted it for me, missed it, many thanks

Comment: Experimentally I noticed that even if you put onSupportNavigateUp() method in your code, if you do not use DrawerLayout in your MainActivity, then navigation up arrow button not displaying.

Comment: @ErcanDuman - as per the documentation, no Up arrow appears when you're on a top level destination (by default, the start destination of your graph).

Comment: Sometimes onNavigateUp() won't work but onSupportNavigateUp() will definitely.

Answer (score 0):

In addition if you want enable up button for fragments you can subclass the toolbar and

```
override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow()
    val navController = (context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host)!!.findNavController()
    setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

and write something like above inside of it , assuming that you're using `AppcompatActivity` which has your `NavHostFragment` so it has a nav controller , so you can set it up with navcontroller here instead of doing this in every fragment as documentations says.

subclassing toolbar has more advantages like you can set a back icon for all fragments in just a single place also you can change font and position of toolbar title which is not supported by the  toolbar out of the box.

it do it some like

```
override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b)
    children.forEach {
        if(it is TextView && !titleSet){
            titleSet  = true
            it.x -= 50
            it.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.poppins_bold)
            return@forEach
        }
    }
}
```

Above solution is not tested in many apps and may not be sufficient for your use case but it worked for me.