# Android, back button navigation with FragmentContainerView close the app instead of going to the previous fragment

Tags: android, navigation

I have an `AppCompatActivity` with a `FragmentContainerView` and a `BottomNavigationView`.
When I navigate from a fragment_A to the fragment_B(which are not in the bottom menu) a back button appears, the problem is that the back button closes the app instead of going back to the previous fragment_A.

My activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:liftOnScroll="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/homeToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_home"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior=".ui.behaviour.TestBehavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the kotlin code:

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityHomeBinding

    private val viewModel: HomeActivityViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.homeToolbar)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_home) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home,
                R.id.navigation_fragment_a,
                R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

This is the action xml:

```
<action
            android:id="@+id/navigate_to_fragment_b"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_b"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left" />
```

This the code I use to obtain the navController reference:

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_home) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

And this is the navigation function that i call from the fragment_A:

```
navController.navigate(R.id.navigate_to_fragment_b)
```

I tried to override the `onBackPressed()` in my activity but it's never gets called.

---

### Update

I have confused the [back button with the up button](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#up_and_back_are_identical_within_your_apps_task).
In my case back button returns to previous fragment but up button close the app.

So my problem is with the UP BUTTON.

UP button appears only when I navigate to the fragment_B, and referring to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#the_up_button_never_exits_your_app) I would say that there is something that does not work because it closes the app for me.

> **The Up button never exits your app**
> If a user is at the app's start destination, then the Up button does not appear, because the Up button never exits the app. The Back button, however, is shown and does exit the app.

Comment: So what is the `<action>` for `navigate_to_fragment_b`? Are you overriding `onBackPressed()` in your Activity?

Comment: I tried to override the onBackPressed() in my activity but it's never gets called.
I updated the question with the action xml.

Comment: Are you sure, that you are not popping fragments from backstack.

Comment: Yes I am quite sure, can I provide some other info?

Comment: Did you override `onSupportNavigateUp()` in activity?

Comment: Thanks to your hint I tried now, in debug I see that this line `Intent upIntent = getSupportParentActivityIntent();` create an intent for the previous activity (InitialActivity starts HomeActivity using `startActivity(Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java))`). This is unexpected to me, it is correct?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that the back button try to return to previous activity instead of going to previous fragment.
This is the code I use in the InitialActivity to start HomeActivity:
`startActivity(Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java))
                finish()`. If I remove `finish()` I notice that the back button returns to InitialActivity. 
Is this the correct behavior?

Comment: This is correct if you don't include the InitialActivity in the navigation components

Comment: Sorry but this is not clear to me. I have InitialActivity that simply initializes some data and then starts HomeActivity. Only HomeActivity has a navigation graph. What should I do?

Comment: I changed the manifest to launch HomeActivity directly. The problem persists so it does not depend on the fact that I use a startActivity intent.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to *ianhanniballake* for the solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56227314/195176)

```
    // Java
    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_fragment).navigateUp()|| super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
```

```
    // Kotlin
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_fragment).navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
```